# Linq query to return the cheapest product, only if it is unique

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I have a list of `Product`s, with the `Price`. I would like to get the the *cheapest* one only if it is *unique*. If there are *more than one* `Product` with the *same* lowest price, it should *not return any*.

In the sample below, for the `uniqProductList` the query should return the `BestOne` while for the `dupProductList`, no product should be returned.

How do I write the *Linq* query ?

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}

List<Product> uniqProductList = new List<Product>() {
    new Product { Name = "GoodOne", Price = 12M },
    new Product { Name = "NiceOne", Price = 12M },
    new Product { Name = "ExpensiveOne", Price = 15M },
    new Product { Name = "BestOne", Price = 9.99M }
};

List<Product> dupProductList = new List<Product>() {
    new Product { Name = "GoodOne", Price = 12M },
    new Product { Name = "NiceOne", Price = 12M },
    new Product { Name = "ExpensiveOne", Price = 15M },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way if you want to do it in a single query:

```
Product result = uniqProductList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Price)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Count() == 1)?
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

- Group the results by price
- Order by price so that the cheapest is the first result
- Take the first result, since we aren't interested in the other ones
- Return the grouping if there is only one result in the group
- Return the value

There's almost certainly some other method that is faster, though.

Comment: Shorter version is `.SingleOrDefault();` instead of `FirstOrDefault(...)?.FirstOrDefault(...)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Replacing the two FirstOrDefault calls with SingleOrDefault makes the call return a Grouping rather than a Product - could you elaborate on how the whole call would be?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `ArgMax` which is *not included* into standard *Linq* but can be implemented manually with a help of `Aggregate`. Having a collection of the cheapest `Product`s we can return `null` if we have more than `1` of them:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<Product> source = ...

  var bests = source
    .Aggregate(new List<Product>(), (s, a) => {
      if (s.Count <= 0 || s[0].Price == a.Price)
        s.Add(a);
      else if (a.Price <= s[0].Price) {
        s.Clear();
        s.Add(a);
      }

      return s;
    });

  Product best = bests.Count == 1 ? bests[1] : default(Product);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error - CS1061 - 'List<Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no accessible extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Product>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Nicola Lepetit: you should *mention* Linq: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Running it, I am getting the following error: Sequence contains more than one element.

Comment: @Nicola Lepetit: I see; it seems we have to check for `Count`  manually

Answer (score 1):

You could group by the elements by their price and getting the cheapest group:

```
var cheapestGrp = uniqProductList.GroupBy(i => i.Price).OrderBy(i => i.Key).First();
```

Then, based on the number of elements of the group, return the only element or return nothing:

```
if (cheapestGrp.Count() > 1)
    return null;
else
    return cheapestGrp.ToList().First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution:

```
public Product? TryGetBestOne(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    var bestProducts = products
        .GroupBy(x => x.Price)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<Product>();

    return bestProducts.Count() == 1 ? bestProducts.Single() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = Products.GroupBy(x => x.Price)
                  .Select(g => new { g.Name, Count = g.Count() 
                          })
                  .Orderby(s.Count)
                  .Select(x.Name, x.Count).FirstOrDefault();    

if(result.Count == 1){
  return result;
}
else{
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` and then use `Where` to get items where there is just one `Count` and then just sort in ascending order:

```
var result = uniqProductList
    .GroupBy(u => u.Price)
    .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, Count = grp.Count(), Items = grp.ToList() })
    .Where(s => s.Count == 1)
    .OrderBy(o=> o.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

An example:

```
List<Product> uniqProductList = new List<Product>() {
            new Product { Name = "GoodOne", Price = 12M },
            new Product { Name = "NiceOne", Price = 12M },
            new Product { Name = "ExpensiveOne", Price = 15M },
            new Product { Name = "BestOne", Price = 9.99M }
};

List<Product> dupProductList = new List<Product>() {
            new Product { Name = "GoodOne", Price = 12M },
            new Product { Name = "NiceOne", Price = 12M },
            new Product { Name = "ExpensiveOne", Price = 15M },
};

var result = uniqProductList
    .GroupBy(u => u.Price)
    .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, Count = grp.Count(), Items = grp.ToList() })
    .Where(s => s.Count == 1)
    .OrderBy(o=> o.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution :

```
 var product = uniqProductList.OrderBy(a => a.Price)
          .GroupBy(a => a.Price).FirstOrDefault()
          .Aggregate(new List<Product>(), (result, item) =>
          {
            result.Add(item);
            if (result.Count() > 1)
                result = new List<Product>();
            return result;
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can get the lowest price first, then you can group them.